# Python Evaluating 8 > 10 To True

Tags: python-2.7, graph, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to write a program to check if a BinaryTree is a BinarySearchTree. This is what I have so far.

```
class BinaryTreeNode:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def insert_right(self, value):
        self.right = BinaryTreeNode(value)
        return self.right

    def insert_left(self, value):
        self.left = BinaryTreeNode(value)
        return self.left


def isBST(node):
    return isBSTHelper(node, float('-inf'), float('inf'))


def isBSTHelper(node, minimum, maximum):
    if node is None:
        return True
    current_node = node.value

    if current_node < minimum or current_node > maximum:
        print current_node, minimum, maximum
        # Somehow, we enter this loop even though minimum < 10 < maximum
        return False

    left_valid = isBSTHelper(node.left, minimum, current_node)
    right_valid = isBSTHelper(node.right, current_node, maximum)

    return (left_valid and right_valid)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bintree = BinaryTreeNode('10')
    bintree.insert_left('8')
    bintree.insert_right('12')
    # This should return True
    print isBST(bintree)
```

I've tried multiple debug print statements and after doing that, I've realized that my function isBSTHelper seems to evaluate current_value, which is 8, to be greater than maximum, which is 10. I cannot figure out why.

Any takers?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I was using the string '8' as opposed to the integer 8 for my test case :)